# Get `\jobname` with normal catcodes

Tags: catcodes, jobname

I would like to create a macro `\myjob` that has the same *value* as `\jobname`, but with letters having catcode 11 instead of 12. The goal is to be able to do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\edef\myjob{\jobname}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{\begingroup%
  \def\@tempa{#1}%
%  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@tempa\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \meaning\@tempa\par%
  \meaning\myjob\par%
  \ifx\@tempa\myjob%
    YES%
  \else%
    NO%
  \fi%
\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\mytest{test}
\end{document}
```

where `\ifx\@tempa\myjob` is true (assuming the correct string is passed to `\mytest`). I would prefer not to detokenize the input string. Rather, I am looking for a different way of defining `\myjob` that "retokenizes" `\jobname`.

Comment: 'Retokenizing' is risky as there might be a `%` or similar: see e-TeX's `\scantokens`

Comment: @JosephWright if a user is silly enough to put `%` or other nonsense in the `\jobname` then I am fine with it causing problems.

Comment: The detokenizing of `\@tempa` contents is much more safer. It can be done by a simple `\@onelevel@sanitize\@tempa`, which does not even require e-TeX. The tokenization method via `\scantokens` is not reliable at all. Depending on the current category code settings and the used characters, the latter method can break with a cryptic error message; also, the result is not even stable in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from Joseph Wright, all I need is `\scantokens`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\edef\myjob{\expandafter\scantokens\expandafter{\jobname\noexpand}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{\begingroup%
  \def\@tempa{#1}%
%  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@tempa\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \meaning\@tempa\par%
  \meaning\myjob\par%
  \ifx\@tempa\myjob%
    YES%
  \else%
    NO%
  \fi%
\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\mytest{test}

\end{document}
```