# Weird behavior of \jobname

Tags: tex-core, jobname

Assume I have a file named `G1 (SK).tex` containing

```
\def\SK{SK}

\def\parse"#1 (#2)"{\def\language{#2}}

\expandafter\parse\jobname

\ifx\SK\language equal\else distinct\fi

\bye
```

When I run it, it prints `distinct`, even if the value of `jobname` is `"G1 (SK)"`. When I use

`\expandafter\parse"G1 (SK)"`

it works as expected and prints `equal`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's probably a category code issue. I think `\jobname` is supposed to have all *other* characters. You get equality with `\edef\SK{\detokenize{SK}}`.

Comment: See also [Get `\jobname` with normal catcodes - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334817/get-jobname-with-normal-catcodes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\jobname` produces characters of category code 12, while the replacement text of `\SK` contains characters of category code 11.

There are several ways to cope with the problem. If you use `pdftex` that supports e-TeX extensions

```
\edef\SK{\detokenize{SK}}

\def\parse"#1 (#2)"{\def\filelanguage{#2}}

\expandafter\parse\jobname

\ifx\SK\filelanguage equal\else distinct\fi

\bye
```

You could also exploit `\pdfstrcmp`:

```
\def\parse"#1 (#2)"{\def\filelanguage{#2}}

\expandafter\parse\jobname

\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{SK}{\filelanguage}=0 equal\else distinct\fi

\bye
```

because `\pdfstrcmp` does string comparison independent of category codes (and expands macros in its arguments).

In any case, you shouldn't do `\def\language`, because `\language` is a TeX primitive.

A more flexible solution with `expl3`.

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \l_bak_file_language_str
\str_set_eq:NN \l_bak_file_language_str \c_sys_jobname_str
\regex_replace_once:nnN { .*? \((.*)\) .* } { \1 } \l_bak_file_language_str

% now the string variable contains the string in parentheses
% extracted from the jobname

\cs_new:Npn \checklanguage
 {
  \str_case:VnF { \l_bak_file_language_str }
   {
    {SK}{Language~is~SK}
    {AB}{Language~is~AB}
    {XYZ}{Language~is~XYZ}
   }
   {Undefined~language}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\checklanguage

\bye
```

This prints “Language is SK”, but if I use a different jobname, say `XYZ(X)`, I get “Undefined language”.

The command `\checklanguage` is fully expandable and so works in `\edef`. The token to execute for each string are up to you and your intended application. Note that you don't need to care about the quotes added if there is a space in the name, because the first lines just extract what's between the (first set of) parentheses.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, do you know whether `regex_replace_once` is implemented using only TeX primitives? It looks very difficult

Comment: @PatrikBak e-TeX is required

Answer (score 4):

`\jobname` assigns category code 12 to all characters except space when it's set. You can get your desired result doing something like this:

```
{
  \catcode`\S=12
  \catcode`\K=12
\gdef\sk{SK}
}
\def\parse"#1 (#2)"{\def\language{#2}}

\expandafter\parse\jobname

\ifx\sk\language equal\else distinct\fi

\bye
```