# TeX \ifx conditional not working for string comparison

Tags: conditionals, programming, strings, jobname

I would like a LaTeX source file to compile in different ways depending on the job name. However, when I run `pdflatex mwe` with `mwe.tex` containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ifx{mwe}\jobname
  true
\else
  false.\jobname.
\fi
\def\mwe{mwe}
\ifx\mwe\jobname
  true
\else
  false.\jobname.\mwe.
\fi
\end{document}
```

the resulting pdf file is "false.mwe. false.mwe.mwe.", while I expected to see "true".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the record, you could have used `\edef\x{\detokenize{mwe}} \edef\y{\jobname} \ifx\x\y...` to compare using `\ifx`

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot.

Comment: Mostly duplicate of [tex core - Weird behavior of \jobname - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561013/weird-behavior-of-jobname)... plus some little details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\ifx` compares only two tokens.  In the first test it compares `{` and `m`, and in the second test it compares the *macro* `\mwe` and *primitive* `\jobname`, which are not exactly the same (even if they expand to the same text).

If you want string comparison, you can use `expl3`'s `\str_if_eq:nnTF` (using `\str_if_eq:eeTF` so that it expands macros before comparing):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \strcompare \str_if_eq:eeTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\strcompare{mwe}{\jobname}
  {true}
  {false.\jobname.}

\def\mwe{mwe}
\strcompare{\mwe}{\jobname}
  {true}
  {false.\jobname.\mwe.}
\end{document}
```

The document prints `true true`.