# Problem with lstlisting and LaTeX3 for exercises repository

Tags: listings, latex3

First of all, sorry by the size of my MWE, I didnt know how to do it smaller.

I was developing some kind of repository of questions for my classes. My purpose is to show one exercise in a pdf document which will be available in a sharedpoint for students , then, after some discussion in class, I can add the solution to the pdf. The same for all my exercises.

So first of all, I have the repository of question : `01_Question.tex`

```
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\text' macro
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}

\addexercise
{S0101}
{Question description}
{Test of the exercise}
{Solution
% here I can use tkiz graphics also
}

\addexercise
{S0102}
{Question description}
{Test of the exercise}
{Solution}
```

Then I have a question manager file: `listQuestionManager.tex`

```
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\addexercise}{m m m m}
{
    \exercise_add:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Question}{m}
{
    \exercise_question:n {#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Solution}{m}
{
    \exercise_solution:n {#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Description}{m}
{
    \exercise_description:n { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\printexercises}{}
{
    \exercise_print:
}

\prop_new:N \g_exercise_texts_prop
\seq_new:N \g_exercise_keys_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \exercise_add:nnnn
{
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_exercise_keys_seq { #1 }
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g_exercise_texts_prop { #1@desc } { #2 }
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g_exercise_texts_prop { #1@text } { #3 }
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g_exercise_texts_prop { #1@sol } { #4 }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \exercise_description:n
{
    \prop_get:NnNT \g_exercise_texts_prop {#1@desc} \l_tmpa_tl
    { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \exercise_question:n
{
    \prop_get:NnNT \g_exercise_texts_prop {#1@text} \l_tmpa_tl
    { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \exercise_solution:n
{
    \prop_get:NnNT \g_exercise_texts_prop {#1@sol} \l_tmpa_tl
    { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
}



\cs_new_protected:Nn \exercise_print:
{
    \seq_map_function:NN \g_exercise_keys_seq \__exercise_print:n
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__exercise_print:n
{
    \noindent
    \textbf{\underline{Id\;Pregunta}:\;} { #1 } 
    \par
    \noindent
    \textbf{Description:\;} \exercise_description:n {#1}    
    \par
    \noindent   
    \textbf{Enunciado:} 
    \\
    \exercise_question:n {#1}
    \par
    \noindent
    \textbf{Solucion:}
    \\ 
    \exercise_solution:n {#1}
    \par
    \addvspace{\topsep}
}

\cs_new_eq:NN \strcompare \str_if_eq:eeTF

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\questionind{Q}
\def\solutionind{S}
\def\questsolind{QS}
\def\finalind{SXXX}

\input{01_Questions.tex}
```

And finally, what I have to compile when I want to add some exercise/solution to the pdf is `01_Practice.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{listQuestionManager.tex}

% This is what I have to change to include question. e.g. "S0101/QS" S0101 is the id of the question, Q means "only question", QS means "Question + Solution"
\newcommand\iterable{
    S0101/QS,
    S0202/Q
    SXXX/QS}



\begin{document}
    
    \section*{Ejercicios}
    \newcounter{int}
    
    \foreach \n/\q in \iterable{
        
        
            \strcompare{\n}{\finalind}
            {
            }{
                \stepcounter{int}
                
                \noindent       
                \textbf{\underline{Pregunta \theint}}
                \vspace{8pt}
                %https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619633/300269  
                \\
                
                \strcompare{\q}{\questionind}
                {
                    \noindent
                    \textbf{Enunciado:}
                    \\
                    \noindent
                    \expandafter\Question\expandafter{\n}   
                }
                \noindent
                %\vspace{80pt}
                
                \strcompare{\q}{\solutionind}
                {
                    \noindent
                    \textbf{Solución:}
                    \\
                    \noindent
                    \expandafter\Solution\expandafter{\n}
                    
                }   
                
                
                \strcompare{\q}{\questsolind}
                {
                    \noindent
                    \textbf{Enunciado:}
                    \\
                    \noindent
                    \expandafter\Question\expandafter{\n}
                    %\parskip=7pt
                    %\parskip=5pt
                    \vspace{10pt}
                    
                    
                    \noindent
                    \textbf{Solución:}
                    \\
                    \noindent
                    \expandafter\Solution\expandafter{\n}
                    
                }
                
                \vspace{20pt}
            }
            %}
        %
    }   

\end{document}
```

Now, I want to use code blocks inside Solution sections. So I used an excercise like this:

```
\addexercise
{SomeID}
{SomeDesc}
{Some Text}
{
\begin{lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
}
```

but it fails. I only see this in the logs, but it does not help to much:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
<inserted text> 
                \relax
l.90    }
        
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 18416 strings out of 475248
 376809 string characters out of 5769538
 1929785 words of memory out of 5000000
 39628 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 563130 words of font info for 55 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 10000i,8n,9995p,474b,859s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: you can not use verbatim environments such as `lstlisting` in the argument of another command.

Comment: You could simplify your example to `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand\hmm[1]{#1}
\begin{document}

\hmm{
\begin{lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
}

\end{document}
`